# SQL How to conditionally sum values with conditions in another table

Tags: sql

I need a query to sum the total available server time for users: each server must be online, on a day that server time is available to the users.

The server status data I have comes from a table like follows (Table1):

```
serverid   status    changedate  changestatusid
server2    Offline   10-02-19    1 
server2    Online    26-02-19    2
server1    Online    01-04-19    3  
server1    Offline   02-05-19    4
server1    Online    06-05-19    5   
server2    Offline   15-07-19    6
```

The available time on each day comes from another table, and depends on the type of user -userclass- (Table2):

```
Location  userclass  date      timeavail 
PERU      type-A     01-04-19  08:00 
PERU      type-B     01-04-19  06:00
USA       type-A     01-04-19  08:00
USA       type-C     01-04-19  07:00
PERU      type-A     02-04-19  08:00
```

Finally, user registration is on another table (Table3):

```
userid  firstname  lastname  userclass  location
user1   Juan       Obrero    type-A     PERU
user2   Michael    Stevens   type-B     USA
user3   Brett      McDonald  type-C     USA
```

What I’ve accomplished so far is this:

```
select tb3.location,
       tb3.userid,
       tb2.date,
       sum(tb2.timeavail) as hours 
from Table3 as tb3
right join Table2 as tb2
on tb2.userclass = tb3.userclass
```

Which sums the total available time from the servers to each user, however how could I take in consideration the server status?

Comment: what's the relationship of table1 and table2?